# Loop in R repeating each i in a loop and then move to the i+1 and so on

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, code-editor

Loop repeating each i in a loop and then move to the i+1 and so on

```
Ang1    
0.063
0.072
0.077
```

I have a column named Ang1. I want to repeat each value few times and then move to the next value.

I wrote following loop but it is repeating all sequence at once instead of one value at a time.

```
for (i in Ang1){
  k=rep(i, 3)
}
```

Output should be like that

```
Ang1
0.063
0.063
0.063    
0.072
0.072
0.072
0.077
0.077
0.077
```

I have a huge data set where each value need to be repeated more than 1000 times, before I move to the next value (i+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep` directly with the each `argument`

```
Ang1 <- c(0.063, 0.072, 0.077)

rep(Ang1, each = 3)
```